# I want multiple records in child table linked to one record in parent table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am using Wordpress 4.2.2 and phpMyAdmin

Maybe some of you have played the MMORPG WoW(World of Warcraft). The WoW website  allows you to **create an account and create multiple characters which are linked to that one specific account.** I'm trying to copy this idea with a primary/foreign key relationship between two tables **using the ID columns**. The columns are linked but they're not doing exactly what I had hoped.

**THE PROBLEM**
I can't add more than one ID from the character_table to a single ID in the wp_user table. In other words, a Wordpress user cannot have more than one character. I have tried inserting it with SQL statements in phpMyAdmin. Only to get this...

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`myth_wp`.`character_table`, CONSTRAINT `character_tableFK` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `wp_users` (`ID`))

I have also tried inserting it with my little character creator page([my character creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X8RP.png)) with the help of a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqfl51HVodI

**wp_user:**
The first table is a default table in Wordpress called wp_user which holds account information for my website like, "ID, Username, Email etc". The ID column has the primary key.

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID       | BigInt(20)  | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| userpass | varchar(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| usrlogin | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Email    | varchar(60) | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**character_table:**
This is the table I created which holds information about a character like, "ID, Race, Class, Level". The ID column has the foreign key.

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID       | BigInt(20)  | NO   | FOR |         | auto_increment |
| race     | varchar(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| class    | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A little more details... There are three wordpress users with ID's of 1, 2 and 4 in the wp_user table. Same ID numbers in the character_table 1, 2, and 4. Unless I add another user in wp_users, I can't add another character. I'm not concerned with how many wordpress users there are, i'm only concerned with having more than one CHARACTER for a single wordpress user

I appreciate the help and feedback. This community always amazes me.

Comment: you foreign key should not be auto_increment!

Comment: I tried turning that off too. The character table simply won't accept more ID's than my wp_user table whether auto_increment is on or off. I would have to make another wordpress user account to be able to make another character. Thank you though, I appreciate the help!